# How to enter bios after unsuccessful windows 7 installation attempt?

Tags: windows-7, boot, installation, bios, uefi

I had Windows 10 on my computer and it was corrupted (couldn't connect to the internet). I decided to install Windows 7. Everything was fine up until it had to reboot mid installation. Then it asked me if I wanted to install Windows 7 as if I hadn't been installing it already. I had pressed "No" thinking it would start all over again. It rebooted and asked me the second time and I pressed No again. After it rebooted the screen was black but the computer seemed to be fully functioning (the fans were spinning/power button is lit up etc). I tried to get into bios/uefi menu by pressing Esc but it won't let me. The screen is always black. The only way to reboot is to unplug the power. It doesnt boot into  the installation CD or my Archlinux USB either. What do I do?

Comment: What is the make and model of your computer?

Comment: @DavidPostill HP Pavilion 500 PC Series. Intel Core i3 3240 @ 3.40GHz, 4.00GB Single-Channel DDR3 @ 798MHz (11-11-11-28), Foxconn 2ADA, 2048MB ATI AMD Radeon HD 8570, 931GB Seagate ST1000DM003-1CH162 (SATA)